# Is there important information in the $HOME/.gradle directory?

Tags: gradle, home-directory

I'm about to backup my (Linux) home directory, and in the process of culling some of the larger files/subdirectories whose contents I dont need (e.g. `.cache`, `.ccache` etc.) - I noticed I have a pretty sizable `.gradle` subdirectory.

I very rarely use the gradle build tool, but I must have used it for something a couple of years back. My question: Is there important information/settings in a user's `.gradle` folder, or is it basically just cached dependencies / gradle's own auto-downloaded data?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the docs:

https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/directory_layout.html#dir:gradle_user_home

> The Gradle user home directory (`$USER_HOME/.gradle` by default) is used to store global configuration properties and initialization scripts as well as caches and log files.

Generally, locally it does not matter. However, more advanced use cases (CI/CD) allow you to share or even relocate certain caches: https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/build_cache.html

The only notable item of importance is a global `gradle.properties` file you may have created. If you did, it would be located at `$GRADLE_USER_HOME/gradle.properties` where `GRADLE_USER_HOME` by default is `$USER_HOME/.gradle`. If there any credentials in there you do not have saved else where, considering backing those up.

Otherwise, it is safe to delete. Granted you do not mind having to redownload dependencies etc. again.

Comment: At the very least I know I don't need to backup anything but the gradle.properties.